# Move to end of string within buffer - Assembly Languge

Tags: string, pointers, assembly, buffer, eol

I am trying to take in a string and then see if the last value in the string is an EOL character. I figured I would use the length of the string read in and then add it to the address of the buffer to find the last element. This does not seem to work.

Edit: I apologize that I did not include more information. Variables are defined as such:

```
  %define BUFLEN 256

  SECTION .bss                    ; uninitialized data section
    buf:    resb BUFLEN                     ; buffer for read
    newstr: resb BUFLEN                     ; converted string
    rlen:   resb 4
```

Then a dos interrupt is called to accept a string from the user like so:

```
    ; read user input
    ;
    mov     eax, SYSCALL_READ       ; read function
    mov     ebx, STDIN              ; Arg 1: file descriptor
    mov     ecx, buf                ; Arg 2: address of buffer
    mov     edx, BUFLEN             ; Arg 3: buffer length
    int     080h
```

Then we go into our loop:

```
  test_endl:
    mov     ecx, [rlen]
    mov     esi, buf
    add     esi, ecx                ; i want to move 'rlen' bytes into buf
    mov     al, [esi]               ; to see what the last element is
    cmp     al, 10                  ; compare it to EOL
    jnz     L1_init
    dec     ecx                     ; and then decrease 'rlen' if it is an EOL
    mov     [rlen], ecx\
```

I am user NASM to compile and writing for an i386 machine.

Comment: I assume you are using `nasm`? Your question doesn't explicitly say. But what would be helpful is if you included in your question the part of the code that also defines `rlen` and `buf`. I'm betting there is an issue in the way you are defining `rlen`

Comment: He _included_ the minimal example, voting this question to close is a _bad_ decision!

Comment: @peterh I would say you are wrong given the circumstances. The poster actually has now modified his original question (which I am only aware of now). When I wrote to close the OP didn't have the variable declaration defined, and because of that it wasn't complete. The size of the variables (which were not known originally could have produced a problem for `mov ecx, [rlen]`. I am willing to RETRACT the close vote now that the OP actually amended his question. Please review the edit history and you'll see it became complete a full day later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the length of the string to the address of the buffer gives access to the byte **behind** the string.

Based on you saying that

- you want to see if the last value **in** the string is an EOL character
- you aim to decrease 'rlen' if it is an EOL (*)

I conclude that you consider the possible EOL character part of the string as defined by its length *rlen*. If you don't then (*) doesn't make sense.

Use `mov al,[esi-1]` to see what the last element is!

```
test_endl:
  mov     ecx, [rlen]
  mov     esi, buf
  add     esi, ecx         ; i want to move 'rlen' bytes into buf
  mov     al, [esi-1]      ; to see what the last element is
  cmp     al, 10           ; compare it to EOL
  jnz     L1_init
  dec     ecx              ; and then decrease 'rlen' if it is an EOL
  mov     [rlen], ecx
```

Comment: Have you also considered without further information that `rlen` might also  be defined as a byte or word, and have you accounted for that in your answer? The problem is that without more information what you suggest may not be all that is wrong.

Comment: We have to trust the OP on this. If he/she writes `mov ecx,[rlen]` I trust he/she knows it is a dword.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many times I have seen on SO that very problem end up being a big issue. The reality is that this is a poorly worded question because it isn't MCVE. I wouldn't go making that assumption with people who are potentially new to assembly language.

Comment: This was the correct answer and worked for my application. Thank you for your help. I also figured out an alternative, longer solution as well that I will post.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer since it now matches the given updated question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much more roundabout way (literally) of getting to the end of the string. I loop through all the characters in the string based on what the size of the counter, rlen, is. Then, once the loop is complete, I make the comparison and decrement rlen as necessary.

```
test_loop:
    mov     al, [esi]               ; get a character
    inc     esi                     ; update source pointer
    dec     ecx                     ; update char count
    jnz     test_loop               ; loop to top if more chars
    cmp     al, 10                  ; comparison
    jne     L1_init                 ; if not EOL jump to L1_init
    mov     ecx, [rlen]             ; decrease the size of rlen if necessary
    dec     ecx
    mov     [rlen], ecx
```